# Change spark _temporary directory path

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, partitioning

Is it possible to change the `_temporary` directory where spark save its temporary files before writing?

In particular, since I am writing single partitions of a table I woud like the temporary folder to be within the partition folder.

Is it possibile?

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: No, there seems to be no way of doing it

Comment: eventually, I've had to override a FileOutputCommitter, to make it work.

Comment: @ArkadiyVerman could you please elaborate how you did that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to use the default  FileOutputCommitter because of its implementation, the FileOutputCommiter creates a **${mapred.output.dir}/_temporary**  subdirectory where the files are written and later on, after being committed, moved to **${mapred.output.dir}**.

In the end, an entire temporary folder deleted. When two or more Spark jobs have the same output directory, mutual deletion of files will be inevitable.

Eventually, I've downloaded ***org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter*** and ***org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter*** (you can name it **YourFileOutputCommitter**) made some changes that allows _temporaly rename

in your driver, you'll have to add following code:

```
val conf: JobConf = new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
conf.setOutputCommitter(classOf[YourFileOutputCommitter])


// update temporary path for committer 
YourFileOutputCommitter.tempPath = "_tempJob1"
```

note: it's better to use **MultipleTextOutputFormat** to rename files because two jobs that write to the same location can override each other.

> *Update*

I've created short post in our tech blog, it has more details
https://www.outbrain.com/techblog/2020/03/how-you-can-set-many-spark-jobs-write-to-the-same-path/

Comment: in the custom committer there is a method without return type, compilation fails .

Comment: how do i set this in spark scala code, i dont have method conf.setOutputCommitter(classOf[YourFileOutputCommitter]).

Comment: it's still there https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setOutputCommitter-java.lang.Class-